# Is it possible to edit the YAML of a release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working on my first Azure DevOps Services release pipeline. I've got a secret in a variable group in the Azure DevOps | Library area. I've been struggling with getting to that secret so I can use it in the release pipeline. I see by this article [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on Microsoft's Docs that I must add that in the `variables` section of the YAML file. However, I've not seen any way to edit the release pipeline YAML file. I can view it, but there appears to be all. If there's a way of editing the YAML file, how do I get to it?

Comment: Sorry it s a bit confusing. From azure devops are you using `pipelines` (defined in yaml) or `releases` (defined through UI) ?

Comment: `releases`, because I don't know of a way to get to the YAML

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that, earlier To enable YAML release pipeline, you need to activate **`Multi-stage YAML pipelines`** in Preview features:

From the [**`Docs`**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/),

> To help make it even easier to edit and update your pipeline, we’ve
> created an in-product editor with IntelliSense smart code completion,
> and an easy task assistant

Comment: Interesting! I'll try it tomorrow when I'm working from home. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you're pointing at.

- If you're using YAML pipelines, you can reference the variable group in your YAML pipeline:

  ```
  variables:
  - group: my-variable-group
  ```
- If you're using the classic mode, you can link the variable group to your pipeline through the UI:
  [image]

Comment: I'm not using the classic mode. Should I?

Comment: You said you're using release pipeline = classic mode. could you add more details / screenshot of you pipeline please ?